# Authenticating into Mongodb docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker

How to use authentication in Mongodb docker container? Create user and use that user authentication in Mongodb containers

While using Mongodb and Python flask application, we want to secure mongodb container with perticular username and password.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the documentation on [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/mongo/), you need to run the image with the `--auth` flag, and then add the initial admin user. Summary of the steps:

**Start the Database**

```
docker run --name some-mongo -d mongo --auth
```

**Add the Initial Admin User**

```
$ docker exec -it some-mongo mongo admin
connecting to: admin
> db.createUser({ user: 'jsmith', pwd: 'some-initial-password', roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ] });
Successfully added user: {
    "user" : "jsmith",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @Vishal If you face any issues while connecting first time using the latest credentials, i suggest you need to create a user with "root" privileges(ie., roles: ["root"]) and login first time with the root account and then you can create as many as users as you want according to various permission levels.